# VBA loop with deleting items

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the code below to loop through invited attendees in an outlook appointment and delete all of them, but it is not working as expected.

```
For Each Item In RestrictedItems
    If Item.Class = olAppointment Then
        For Each Attendee In Item.Recipients
            Attendee.Delete
        Next Attendee
    End If
Next Item
```

Comment: Instead of `For...Each` use an index loop that steps backwards.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is reported with monotonous regularity so it is surprising that your searches haven't led you to a solution.  The issue you are experiencing occurs because you are changing the set of items that you are enumerating by deleting items.  I.e when you delete item 2, what was item 3 now becomes item 2 BUT the counter in the VBA loop doesn't know that this has happened so increments to 3 and consequently the next item to be deleted is the current Item 3 (which was Item 4).  This problem can be overcome by only deleting items outside the range that is left to be processed, i.e. deleting Item 7 is not an issue if you are counting down as item 6 will not have changed its position.  Thus you need to use

```
For myIndex =Item.Recipients.Count to 1 Step -1 ' Because collections start at 1 not 0

    Item.Recipients.Item(myIndex).delete

Next
```